# Quantlib USDLibor() method

Tags: derivatives

I'm attempting to shift both a discount and projection curve but am having trouble passing through the VanillaSwap() because of the Ibor input requirement -- I'm trying to calculate the dv01 of a US dollar swap, which requires the base and shifted (up, down) 3mL curve and SOFR curve. How do I pass the shifted 3mL curve through the ql.USDLibor() method? I am receiving an error.

I started with dates and discount factors to generate US3mL and SOFR objects.

I then created DiscountCurve (US3mL, SOFR) objects using the dates,df lists.

```
US3mL = ql.DiscountCurve(curve_US3mL_dates, curve_US3mL_df, ql.Thirty360(), ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond))
SOFR = ql.DiscountCurve(curve_USSOFR_dates, curve_USSOFR_df, ql.Actual360(), ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond))
shift = 0.0001
discount_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(SOFR)
discount_curve_shiftUp = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(discount_curve, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(shift)))
discount_curve_shiftDown = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(discount_curve, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(-shift)))
libor_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(US3mL)
libor_curve_shiftUp = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(libor_curve, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(shift)))
libor_curve_shiftDown = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(libor_curve, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(-shift)))
libor3M_index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'),libor_curve) 
#libor3M_index_shiftUp = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'), libor_curve_shiftUp) 
#libor3M_index_shiftDown = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'), libor_curve_shiftDown)
```

The last two commented lines of code are failing but the Ibor object must be passed through VanillaSwap() as the "index" input.

Answer (score 3):

Don't change the index, relink or modify the curve instead.

For the first method (relink), set up the index as:

```
libor_curve = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle(US3mL)
libor3M_index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'), libor_curve)
```

and build the vanilla swap using `libor3M_index`.  When you want to shift the curve up:

```
libor_curve.linkTo(
    ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(US3mL),
                                 ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(shift))))
```

the index, and indirectly the swap, will use the new curve next time you call their methods.  When you are done, call

```
libor_curve.linkTo(US3mL)
```

to reset the curve to the original level.

For the second method, set up as:

```
spread = ql.SimpleQuote(0.0)
libor_curve = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(US3mL),
                                           ql.QuoteHandle(spread))
libor3M_index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'), libor_curve)
```

so the spreaded curve equals `US3mL` (since the spread is 0).  Build the swap, and when you want to shift the curve up or down execute:

```
spread.setValue(shift)  # or spread.setValue(-shift)
```

Again, the curve will update and the swap will use the new level.  To get back to square one, run

```
spread.setValue(0.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` will return a YieldTermstructure but for the `ql.USDLibor contructor` you need a `ql.YieldTermStructureHandle`.

Change the last two lines to:

```
libor3M_index_shiftUp = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'), ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(libor_curve_shiftUp))
libor3M_index_shiftDown = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'), ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(libor_curve_shiftDown))
```